How do I get node's core modules working with Angular v18?
I'm attempting to use microphone-stream which depends on readable-stream in an Angular v18 application.  When running locally I receive a series of errors in the console related to globals, Buffer, and process objects all missing, which are core modules from node.  I believe these must be polyfilled into the app, but I can't figure out how to do this.
There appears to be a very good vite plugin to do this: vite-plugin-node-polyfills but it seems that the vite configuration for angular can't be customized with plugins.
My app is using the standard Angular application builder (from angular.json):
...
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
...

I did try creating installing the process and buffer and including them in a polyfill like this:
window.global = window
var process = require('process')
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer

But that didn't work either.  I do realize they are quite old.
